# Angular $http GET not passing string to backend. Undefined?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, get, routes

I am trying to use .find() via Mongoose to GET a specific item based on its item_id (different from MongoDB assigned _id). However, nothing gets passed to the backend. The console.log(item) in my route file returns an empty object.

The item looks like this:

```
var item = {
   item_id : "String Identifier",
   desc: "String Description about item"
}
```

My Angular Controller:

```
// itemCtrl.js
App.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.item= $stateParams.itemId;     

    $scope.getItem = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:3000/items/:itemId', $scope.item)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log("Grabbing a single item with id " + data.item_id);
                $scope.item= data;
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
});
```

My Express backend routing:

```
// Item-Route.js
var express=  require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

var Item = mongoose.model('Item ');

router.get('/items/:itemId', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);                        // returns {}
    Item.find({trip_id: req.body.item_id}, function(err, item){
        if(err){console.log(next(err))}
        console.log(item);                        // returns []
        res.json(item);                           
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here? Many thanks! :)

Comment: shouldn't `req.body.item_id` be `req.body.itemId` ?

Comment: `req.body.itemId` I think belongs to the `_id` assigned by mongo (i think). `item_id` is an attribute I made for testing purposes.

Comment: you have `route.get('.../:itemId')` so this is the id angular sends isn't it? also I think it is => `req.params.itemId`

Comment: Changing it to `req.body.itemId` gives me the same error. Changing it to `req.body` gives me error "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Comment: not `body` sorry , since it is a `get` and not `post` you should `req.params.itemId`

Comment: `re.params.itemId` returns `undefined`, as does using `req.params` and `req.params.item_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104118/discussion-between-koox00-and-kangze-huang).

Comment: Could you post the code where you are app.use'ing the router you create? Also, did you mean to have a space in 'Item '?

Answer (score 2):

As its get method you should be passed parameter in url itself like below

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/items/'+ $scope.item)
```

Then change server method to read parameter from `URL` rather than body.

```
router.get('/items/:itemId', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.body);                        // returns {}
    Item.find({trip_id: req.itemId}, function(err, item){
        if(err){console.log(next(err))}
        console.log(item);                        // returns []
        res.json(item);                           
    });
});
```

Comment: That fixed one of my problems, thank you Pankaj! I still receive an empty array in my backend though.

Comment: @KangzeHuang I can't help you in mongo. I haven't used it ever :(

Comment: Its not mongo, its the code between front and back end. My backend is not receiving any params :S

Comment: @KangzeHuang quick change, you should change `req.body.item_id`  to `req.item_id` then

Comment: Changing it to `req.item_id` results in `undefined`. There is nothing in `req.item_id` nor `req.body.item_id`

Comment: @KangzeHuang oh my good.. Ideally it should be `req.itemId` as router parameter is `:itemId`

Answer (score 0):

In your Express backend, I think you should get the `body-parser` from `npm` into the code to expose the req.body.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

The above snippet should be in your main node code so that all Http request will have the same exposure.

Please refer http://expressjs.com/en/api.html in `req.body` section.

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By
>   default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing
>   middleware such as body-parser and multer.